# Converting featurecollection properties to image bands in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api

I want to do a vector to raster conversion as demonstrated [here](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/guides/reducers_reduce_to_image), except that the output image includes multiple bands corresponding to the different featurecollection properties.

I actually figured it out below:

```
// Load a collection of US counties.
var counties = ee.FeatureCollection('TIGER/2018/Counties');

// make list of properties by hand
var properties = ['ALAND', 'AWATER']
print('properties', properties)

// iterate over the list of properties to create an image. bands are now in a sinlge img
var img_list = ee.Image(properties.map(function(property) {
  return counties.select([property])
    .reduceToImage([property], ee.Reducer.first())
    .rename([property])
}))
print('image list', img_list)
```

But, I have a featurecollection with lots of attributes and I'd rather not manually write out the list of properties to iterate over. I thought this would work, but when I iterate over this new list, the output is a list of images with bands defined within each element. Why is this different and is there any way to convert it to the output from the previous code chunk?

```
var properties2 = counties.first().propertyNames().sort().slice(0, 2) //doesn't work properly for some reason
print('properties2', properties2)

// iterate over the list of properties to create an image. bands are nested in each feature, not in a sinlge img
var img_list2 = ee.Image(properties2.map(function(property) {
  return counties.select([property])
    .reduceToImage([property], ee.Reducer.first())
    .rename([property])
}))
print('image list2', img_list2)
```

Comment: Alternatively, is there a way to include a list of properties in `reduceToImage`? The docs indicate that "properties" can be selected from each feature.

Comment: Answering a related question...```var img = counties
  .reduceToImage({
    properties: properties2,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.firstNonNull().forEach(properties2)
  });```